# What data structures to use for dendrogram?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have been searching how to implement a dendrogram, used to depict hierarchical clustering, efficiently. currently I using a a regular expression to parse and show it like a tree structure as shown below.

```
[[2,1],[3]]
```

This means there are three documents and level 1 contains two clusters, one containing documents 2 and 1 and the other contains only document 3.
As we get clusters after cutting the dendrogram at a particular level. cutting the shown shown regular expression is difficult and not always give proper clusters.

What data structures and representation we should use so that getting clusters from dendrogram is comparitively easy.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a pointer-representation as used by the SLINK algorithm.

It's fairly easy: a reference to the parent object, and a distance where they join clusters.

Here, it would be

```
2 parent 1   height 1
1 parent 3   height 2
3 parent nil height inf
```

For extracting clusters, just delete all edges that have a too high join height.